# Filter on values present as a list of objects in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I am stuck a place where I am not able to construct a query that will help me query a particular field which is actually a list of objects.
Sample document:

```
"sample_object" : {
    "name" : "TRS",
    "name_number" : 2096873,
    "dob" : "2011-02-09",
    "sample_nested_object_1" : {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "example name"
    },
    "sample_nested_object_list_1" : [
      {
          "id" : 15,
          "number" : 12
      },
      {
          "id" : 18,
          "number" : 15
      }
    ],
    "sample_nested_object_list_2" : [
      {
          "id" : 2958179,
          "name" : "example name 1",
          "type" : "example type"
      },
      {
          "id" : 2958180,
          "name" : "example name 2",
          "type" : "example type"
      }
    ],
    "sample_nested_object_2" : {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "sample name"
    }
}
```

I have successfully made queries that filter according to ***name***, ***name_number***, ***dob***.

I have to query the data set according to the filters applied in the front end. So I would receive a list of ***id(s)*** for **sample_nested_object_list_1** and have to find the **sample_object(s)** which have **sample_nested_object_list_1** with the *id(s)* provided. Also have to do the same for **sample_nested_object**.

**UPDATE:**

Index mapping:

```
sample_object= {
    'name': StringField(),
    'name_number': IntegerField(),
    'dob': DateField(),
    'sample_nested_object_1': ObjectField(
        properties={
            'id': IntegerField(),
            'name': StringField(),
        }
    ),
    'sample_nested_object_list_1': NestedField(
        properties={
            'id': IntegerField(),
            'number': IntegerField(),
        }
    ),
    'sample_nested_object_list_2': NestedField(
        properties={
            'id': IntegerField(),
            'name': StringField(),
            'type': StringField(),
        }
    ),
    'sample_nested_object_2': ObjectField(
        properties={
            'id': IntegerField(),
            'name': StringField(),
        }
    ),
}
```

Query:

I am unable to think of how to construct a query if I wanted to retrieve a list of *sample_object(s)*, of which have *sample_nested_object_list_1* with *id* as 15, 16 and also *sample_nested_object_1* with an id of 6.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far? And also your index mapping please

Comment: @Val what exactly would you like to see? My document structure and queries?

Comment: The queries you tried + your index mapping

Comment: @Val have posted an update, hope it's helpful. I have used django-elasticsearch-dsl package to create documents.

Comment: @Val we can also continue the discussion in chat.